# Can the null character to be passed to argv in the middle of a string?

Tags: c, linux, exec, argv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```

The following output (run in bash on Ubuntu) shows that 'xyz' is not passed in argv. I want to make sure that this is the limitation of the OS but not the shell. So it would not be possible to pass a null character in the middle of a string in argv. Could anybody confirm? Thanks.

```
$ ./main.exe $'abc\000xyz' 7 | xxd
00000000: 6162 6300 3700 53                        abc.7.S
```

Comment: try with python as a shell. Looks like undefined/implementation defined to me

Comment: The question is where the limitation comes from. Is it from C, OS or shell?

Comment: can't even run it from python "embedded null character"

Comment: duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316232/how-to-pass-x00-as-argument-to-program

Comment: this answer allows to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31739648/6451573

Comment: So the limitation is from the OS. But OS is built on C. So the ultimate limitation is from C? But the direct limitation is from the OS?

Comment: Maube related, [How to find the main function's entry point of elf executable file without any symbolic information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9885545/608639) The question leads you to `__libc_start_main` for Linux ELF binaries. Also see [How main() is executed on Linux](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue84/hawk.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if there's '\0' character in command line input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560779/what-if-theres-0-character-in-command-line-input)

Answer (score 0):

All program start by `exec` calls, despite OS implementations, lets see what does POSIX standard says about [`exec` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

> int execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);

`argv` are arguments passed to the program, `envp` are environment variables.

> The argv and environ arrays are each terminated by a null pointer. The null pointer terminating the argv array is not counted in argc.
>
> The argument argv is an array of character pointers to null-terminated strings.

So, it is very easy to conclude:

1. Empty (zero length) string can be passed to `argv`
2. `NULL` string can't be passed to argv, it will terminate `argv`, and discard all following arguments.
3. any string in `argv` can't contain `\x0` character, `\x0` will terminate the current parameter string.

### Explain what happened when run

```
python -c 'print "\x30\x00\x31"' | xargs --null prog
```

Try:

```
python -c 'print "\x30\x00\x31"' | strace -f xargs --null echo
```

We can find:

```
...
...
...
read(0, "0\0001\n", 4096)               = 4
...
...
...
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f09f46d9850) = 21232
strace: Process 21232 attached
...
...
...
[pid 21232] execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "0", "1\n"], 0x7ffe5ccd7638 /* 74 vars */ <unfinished ...>
```

It shows that `xargs` potentially separate argument containing `\x0` into two arguments when calling `prog`. Not done by shell, not done by OS, libc, but `xargs`

Comment: So the limitation is from exec? But the OS can support none zero terminate strings if there is another way call external programs? Why xargs is relevant here?